# How to create a toggle active button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a toggle button consisting eight buttons. If seven out of the toggle buttons are clicked it toggles two classes(and changes it's CSS styles). 
If one(the daily button) out of the toggle buttons is clicked it toggles the styles of the other seven.

This is my code:

The toggleclass(this) function I predefined toggles the class1 to a class2 CSS style.

I tried doing this

```
<div id="menu1">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#hey').click(function()
{
         if($('#btnDiv,#btnDiv1,#btnDiv2,#btnDiv3,#btnDiv4,#btnDiv5,#btnDiv6').hasClass('class1')){
     $('#btnDiv,#btnDiv1,#btnDiv2,#btnDiv3,#btnDiv4,#btnDiv5,#btnDiv6').toggleClass('class2')
  }else{
    $('#btnDiv,#btnDiv1,#btnDiv2,#btnDiv3,#btnDiv4,#btnDiv5,#btnDiv6').toggleClass('class2')
  }

});

});



                        <div class="cols"><button id="btnDiv" onclick="toggleclass(this);monday();" class="class1"><h5>MONDAY</h5></button></div>
                        <div class="cols"><button id="btnDiv1" onclick="toggleclass(this);tuesday();" class="class1"><h5>TUESDAY</h5></button></div>
                        <div class="cols"><button id="btnDiv2" onclick="toggleclass(this);wednesday();" class="class1"><h5>WEDNESDAY</h5></button></div>
                        <div class="cols"><button id="btnDiv3" onclick="toggleclass(this);thursday();" class="class1"><h5>THURSDAY</h5></button></div>
                        <div class="cols"><button id="btnDiv4" onclick="toggleclass(this);friday();" class="class1"><h5>FRIDAY</h5></button></div>
                        <div class="cols"><button id="btnDiv5" onclick="toggleclass(this);saturday();" class="class1"><h5>SATURDAY</h5></button></div>
                        <div class="cols"><button id="btnDiv6" onclick="toggleclass(this);sunday();" class="class1"><h5>SUNDAY</h5></button></div>
                        <div class="cols"><button id="hey" onclick="toggleclass(this);daily();showdaily();" class="class1"><h5>DAILY</h5></button></div>
```

But it doesn't work. Help me out please

What do I do to get the daily button to change the styles of other buttons(if they are clicked) to class 1 when clicked and change back to class2 again

A straightforward answer using raw JavaScript would be truly appreciated as I'm pretty new to JavaScript.. :)

Comment: try it yourself first rather than jumping to SO for complete solution.

Comment: Man honestly I've tried nothing works ...I'm new to JavaScript

Comment: Please post an example of what you've tried first, then we would be glad to help.

Comment: you say you've tried nothing works... what have you tried? that's kind of what we're asking. I've posted a solution that "works," but without knowing what you have that DOESN'T work, you'll never really get WHY it didn't work. If I give you the code, you've got the code. If you have to fix YOUR code, you've got the concept.

Comment: Ah, so you're using jQuery for this? That's what the $ usually indicates.

Comment: I have added the part I tried ...using jquery

Comment: Ah. OK, so take a look at my answer below, it is done in pure vanilla javascript. Look at the classList property, it will allow you to do what it sounds like you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the link its really helpful ..toggling the class of the other seven buttons ..

Comment: What Im really hoping to get is to get the seven buttons to class 1 when  daily is clicked ..The user has the option of clicking on or more of the seven buttons....but then if the daily is clicked the one or more button will revert to class1...

Comment: Updated my first example to reflect that, and I think the code using YOUR code (the jQuery version) does as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this as a "learning exercise," then you're doing yourself no favors with all the extra HTML in there. I'd even go so far as to get rid of the divs containing each button, but that's just me.

So I'll post a starting point, but this is just an off-the-cuff thing, YMMV. Logically, walk through what you actually want to happen: when a button is clicked, you want to set ALL other buttons to "class1", and then you want to set the currently clicked button to "class2". Research using the javascript classList attribute, it's very handy for this.

I did edit this, as you're looking to TOGGLE the clicked button, so now the code sets all sibling buttons back to the class1, but then the last two lines actually toggle the class1/class2 rather than forcing the button on. For more on what you can do with classList, look at [this](https://alligator.io/js/classlist/).

Third time through. You not only want to be able to toggle the classes, but you want that select all button to toggle the selection of everything? Turn them all ON, turn them all OFF, or simply toggle each one? I've got it so that clicking 'Daily' will toggle all the selected buttons. Again, largely off-the-cuff, and largely playing here.

Based on your comment, clicking on 'Daily' toggles ALL day buttons to class1. I've commented out the section in the day handling to make the day selection be exclusive, but its still there if you need.

```js
// First, store references to the bits we'll manipulate.
var menu = document.querySelector("#menu1");
var dayBtnEls = document.querySelectorAll(".day-button");
var allBtnEl = document.querySelector("#hey");

// Now, rather than adding them in the HTML, I'll
//   attach my event listeners. The menu listens
//   for clicks on the buttons, and the '#hey' button
//   also has a listener. I could have done it all
//   within that single menu listener, as that is
//   also checking if the clicked button is #hey, but
//   I figured "what the hey..."
menu.addEventListener("click", toggleDays);
allBtnEl.addEventListener("click", toggleAll);

/****
 * Without knowing for sure, I've simply set the
 *  toggleAll function to go through all the day
 *  buttons and toggle their class1/class2. So having
 *  one of the buttons selected and clicking 'Daily'
 *  will leave all but that one selected.
 * It's really up to you what you want for the toggle
 *  behavior, this is mostly just an example of what
 *  you COULD do.
 ****/
function toggleAll(event){
  if (event.target.innerText == "Select All") {
  // go through all the day button els.
  for (var i=0; i<dayBtnEls.length; i++){
    // toggle their class1/class2 
    dayBtnEls[i].classList.add("class1");
    dayBtnEls[i].classList.remove("class2");
  }
  event.target.innerText = "Deselect All";
  } else {
  // go through all the day button els.
  for (var i=0; i<dayBtnEls.length; i++){
    // toggle their class1/class2 
    dayBtnEls[i].classList.remove("class1");
    dayBtnEls[i].classList.add("class2");
  } 
  event.target.innerText = "Select All";
  }
}

/****
 * again, without knowing what you're trying to do,
 *  I've set it so that clicking on a day button
 *  forces all the other day buttons to be toggled
 *  back to class1, then the clicked element will
 *  toggle back-and-forth from class1 to class2.
 ****/
function toggleDays(event){
  // as we're listening at the menu level, and #hey
  //  is a child of menu, we need to filter that out.
  if(event.target.id != "hey") {
  var thisDayEl = event.target;
  /**** 
   * I'm commenting out this section, as it seems you
   *  don't want to have it be an exclusive toggle.
   *  I don't want to delete it yet, as I don't know 
   *  for sure, but.
   *
  // set ALL buttons back to class 1...
  for (var i=0; i<dayBtnEls.length; i++){
    if(dayBtnEls[i] != thisDayEl) {
    dayBtnEls[i].classList.remove("class2");
    dayBtnEls[i].classList.add("class1");  
    
    }
  }
  ****/
  
  // Now, set just the clicked button to class2
  thisDayEl.classList.toggle("class2")
  thisDayEl.classList.toggle("class1"); 
  }
}
```

```css
.class1 {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.class2 {
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: #333;
}
.cols {
float: left;
}
.cols button {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu1">

  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv" class="day-button class1">MONDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv1" class="day-button class1">TUESDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv2" class="day-button class1">WEDNESDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv3" class="day-button class1">THURSDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv4" class="day-button class1">FRIDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv5" class="day-button class1">SATURDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv6" class="day-button class1">SUNDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="hey" class="all-button class1">Select All</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Doing the same thing WITH YOUR CODE, with a few very minor changes. Basically, rather than that really long selector list, I added another class to all the day buttons and I use THAT to gather them. I added a listener for the day buttons being clicked on that simply toggles their class1/class2, and the if statement you had in the daily button handler was doing the same thing in either case, so I just got rid of the if. Here is THAT example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".day-button").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("class1").toggleClass("class2");
  })
  $('#hey').click(function() {
    $('.day-button').removeClass('class2').addClass("class1");
  });
});
```

```css
.class1 {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.class2 {
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu1">

  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv" class="day-button class1">MONDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv1" class="day-button class1">TUESDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv2" class="day-button class1">WEDNESDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv3" class="day-button class1">THURSDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv4" class="day-button class1">FRIDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv5" class="day-button class1">SATURDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="btnDiv6" class="day-button class1">SUNDAY</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols">
    <button id="hey" class="all-button class1">DAILY</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If Monday to Sunday is clicked the button doesn't change  and the Daily doesn't do anything . Im really confused here . I have very little knowledge of JavaScript

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: I use google chrome usually but I recently started using Mozilla Firefox

Comment: Well, I've looked at it on firefox, on chrome, on an older IE and on Safari. it's doing what I've asked it to do. Do you have your developers console open? Are you getting some sort of error message? As I say, in every browser I got, its working fine.

Comment: Is it not doing anything? Is it doing something unexpected? Are you seeing any error messages in the console? "Not working" is rather too vague.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<style>
  .class1 {
    color: red;
  }
  .class2 {
    color: green;
  }
</style>

<div>
<button class="class1" onclick="changeClass(event)">Click me</button>
<button class="class1" onclick="changeClass(event)">Click me</button>
</div>

<script>
function changeClass(e) {
    if (e.target.className.trim() === 'class1') {
     e.target.className = 'class2';
  } else {
     e.target.className = 'class1';
  }
}

</script>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/g12ua8d1/